# ¿Problemas al modificar una foto por otra LARAVEL?

Tags: laravel

tengo un problema, que he copiado un código de otros proyectos de la empresa y tengo un problema que no se porque no se actualiza la ruta ni se sube de manera local la imagen.

No me presenta ningún mensaje de error, he visto que si entra al proceso de eliminar la foto localmente, pero de la BD nunca, y cuando quiero que se actualize el nombre de esa foto no sucede nada, como que después de eliminar se sale y envia el correo diciendo que el proyecto a sido modificado.

P.D. Debo aclarar que el proyecto esta siendo realizado con Laravel.

**Formulario HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="/proyecto/{{$traerProyecto->idProyecto}} " >
@method('PUT')
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                <label>Subir imagen (Portada del Proyecto)</label>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control-file"  name="fotoPrincipal" id="foto" accept="image/*">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-12" id="mostrarImagen">
                    <img src="" width="150px" height="120px" id="previsualizarImagenes" style="display:none">
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

**Código JQUERY**

```
  <script>

    function readURL(input){
      if(input.files && input.files[0]){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e){
          //asignar el atributo src.
          $("#previsualizarImagenes").css("display", "block");
          $('#previsualizarImagenes').attr('src', e.target.result)
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      }
    }

    //Se asigna el listener al input
    $('#foto').change(function(){
      readURL(this);
    });
  </script>
```

**Controlador GUARDAR:**

```
$proyecto = new Proyecto;
            $proyecto->nombreProyecto = $request['txtNombreProyecto'];
            $proyecto->idPais = $request['cboPais'];
            $proyecto->idRegion = $request['cboRegion'];
            $proyecto->idComuna = $request['cboComuna'];
            $proyecto->idProvincia = $request['cboProvincia'];
            $proyecto->codigoEmpresa = 3;
            $proyecto->estadoProyecto = 7;
            $proyecto->save();

            if($request->hasFile('fotoPrincipal')){
                $nombreArchivo = "";
                $file =  $request['fotoPrincipal'];
                $nombreArchivo = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $file->move(public_path() . '/img/proyecto/', $nombreArchivo);

                $imagen = new FotoProyecto;
                $imagen->nombreArchivo = $nombreArchivo;
                $imagen->idProyecto = $proyecto->idProyecto;
                $imagen->save();
            }

            toastr()->success('Proyecto registrado exitosamente!');
            return view('proyecto.create', compact('paises','region','comuna','tipoPropiedad','provincia','traerImagenes'));
```

**Controlador EDITAR:**

```
 $actualizarFoto = FotoProyecto::where('idProyecto','=',$actualizarProyecto->idProyecto)->firstOrFail();

            $actualizarFoto->nombreArchivo = $request['fotoPrincipal'];

            if($request->hasFile('fotoPrincipal')){
                if ($actualizarFoto->nombreArchivo) {
                    File::delete(public_path() . '/img/proyecto/' . $actualizarFoto->nombreArchivo);    
                }

                $nombreArchivo = "";
                $file =  $request->file('fotoPrincipal');
                $nombreArchivo = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
                Input::file('fotoPrincipal')->move(public_path() . '/img/proyecto/' , $nombreArchivo);
                /*$file->move(public_path() . '/img/proyecto/', $nombreArchivo);

                $actualizarFoto->nombreArchivo = $nombreArchivo;*/
                $actualizarFoto->nombreArchivo = $nombreArchivo;
                $actualizarFoto->fill( $request->all() );
                $actualizarFoto->save();
            }
```

Comment: podrias mostrar el codigo en el cual subes tu imagen..., no veo ningun formulario, ajax, fetch o axios  para la subida de la foto.

Comment: Pss no he ocupado nada de eso, solo ocupe el Jquery para que mostrara la imagen que seleccionara en el input, y el resto se subiera por metodo POST a través de laravel. @Shassain

Comment: El formulario (`{{Form::open()}}` o <form>) es muy importante al momento de subir imagenes ya que debes de incluir el multipart/form-data o files=>true, por esa razon queria ver tu form.

Comment: Vale gracias, eso me faltaba, el multipart lo habia puesto en el create pero no en el edit. @Shassain